# Звук Н в словах-отрицаниях разных языков

Tags: этимология, фонетика

__Добавлю в первой строке извинение за широту темы и выход за рамки языка русского. Просто здесь я вижу людей, которые, по моему счету, по-настоящему *шарят* в языковедении._

А я с детства помню, как легко мне удалось выучить слово "No", услышанное когда-то давно в каком-то мультфильме с не самым качественным дубляжем. И вот в ту детскую пору мне очень нравилось, что про какой бы новый язык я не узнавал, слово, обозначающее отрицание, обязательно имело в себе звук Н. No, nein, non, нема. И всю свою последующую жизнь я считал это аргументом к тому, что все языки произошли от одного, Первого, что они имеют общие корни. Пока в одну из *уже* февральских ночей не взбрело мне в голову:

"Так что же такое страшное или неприемлемое было связано у древних людей со звуком Н? Есть ли какое-то объяснение тому, что отрицание во многих языках связано с одним и тем же звуком? Наверняка, кто-то уже задумывался над этим вопросом."

Собственно, последнее и побудило меня задать столь нескромный вопрос- ведь для того и сайт.

Answer (score 3):

Интересный вопрос. Вы правы, во многих языках, но не во всех. Долго удивлялась, изучая греческий язык, что "нет" по-гречески - "охи" (όχι), а "да" – "нэ" (ναί).  Теперь, благодаря вашему вопросу, заинтересовалась, почему утверждение начинается с "н". Буду искать ответ как на ваш вопрос, так и на свой.

Comment: Спасибо за указание на греческий язык) 
Теперь попробую найти слова-отрицания из других языков в переводчиках, чтобы проверить их на наличие звука Н.

Comment: В греческом отрицание НЕ - **δεν** (den). Так что Н присутствует)))

Comment: Ага щаз...

Answer (score 3):

Рискую показаться смешным, но может, это связано с первыми, долингвистическими междометьями, которыми пользовались первобытные люди? Представьте себе ребёнка, которому суют в рот холодную/невкусную кашу. Что он непроизвольно "скажет" в этот момент? Что-то, содержащее звук "н", так как непроизвольное движение языка, препятствующее проникновению в рот нежелательного продукта, именно такое.

Comment: Спасибо за прекрасное предположение) 
Думаю, что пока буду придерживаться этой теории.

Answer (score 1):

Бросьте, при чем тут древние люди?

В греческом, например, нет ничего даже отдаленно похожего на отрицание с НЕ.
А ведь это язык индоевропейской семьи, т.е. близкий к нам.

Comment: что такое "бросте"? (пользуйтесь современными браузерами - они исправляют очепятки)

Comment: Фу... Вам поругаться не с кем?
Или вы все-таки мульт Груманта?

Comment: не... я просто напился. (ну, вы же не обиделись?)

Comment: Заранее предупрежу, что я не Грумант или ALEXIN) 
Спасибо за указание на греческий язык, но его родственность с нашим скорее не сыграет вам на руку. Ведь существует множество других языков, которые, наверняка, совсем нам не родны, но в отрицании имеют звук Н. Тогда, возможно, этот звук что-то для людей да обозначал еще множество веков назад, а греки использовали "запасной вариант".

Comment: >Заранее предупрежу, что я не Грумант или ALEXIN)   
  
Вы в этом уверены? Особенно в последнем? С чего бы тут упоминать персонажа, которого все благополучно забыли?

ЗЫ Серьезно я ваш текст не комментирую. Самому не смешно?